# how to know which tool is appropriate for automating website?

Tags: automated-testing, web-application

I am very much confused which **tool** to be used for a **web based project** on **what basis** we should **choose an automation tool**?

Comment: What confuses you? What did you try to choose a tool upto now? Maybe you can also give us some context for what kind of web-application you are picking a tool. Also its unclear what your question is, do you need advice for tools or a strategy to decided which tool to pick.

Comment: yes you are right "strategy to decided which tool to pick."...please brief me about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must consider what are your needs, and measure those needs against tools which can meet most or all of those needs.

When I consider a test automation tool, here are some general needs I measure the potential tools against:
http://www.allthingsquality.com/2010/04/things-i-like-to-have-in-my-test.html

Comment: @sameerjoshi - Do you have some other way (perhaps an additional tool) to cover the other 20% of the "must haves"? If not, then you need another tool. "Must have" means you cannot do without it.

Answer (score 1):

When choosing any tool you need to evaluate the options available to you.
First step is to get a list of tools that are out there (google is your friend).

Before I begin evaluating  I tend to make a list of criteria and give each tool a mark out of 10, for example;

- Features – Does the tool offer the features you think you will need?
- Usability – How usable is the system?
- Scalability – As the number of tests you are performing increases,
  can the tool support this?
- Learning curve – Does the tool use existing technologies/languages
  you are familiar with or do you need to learn again from scratch?
- Cost – Always important!!!
- Community Support – If you need help, are there questions on Stack ;)
- Integration – will the tool integrate with other tools, eg will it
  run on Jenkins?

Hopefully this will help you narrow down your options to one or two.

At this point I would tend to suggest putting together a small proof of concept to get a feel of the tool.  No matter how appealing the tool's website or demo is, don't put all your eggs in one basket until you have got it working yourself!

Answer (score 0):

If you have knowledge of programming language like java, C# etc., you can go for Selenium Webdriver or Selenium RC. Its very nice tool which is widely used, with many functions to automate web based applications. (And its open source too).

If you need tool with less programming headache, you can use Robot Framework, Which internally uses Selenium webdriver itself. But its Keyword driven, you can save your self from coding.

http://www.seleniumhq.org/
http://robotframework.org/

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This does not answer the question, the question how to select a tool, not what tool should I select.

Comment: yes you are right Niels van Reijmersdal .

Answer (score 0):

Personally

1. I always choose automation tool basing on the main programming language of the product under test
2. I also try to use swiss-army-knife options if possible, for instance performance testing tool for functional automation instead of [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) or [Watir](http://watir.com/) or whatever as:

   - almost all of them provide record-and-replay feature which simplifies and speeds up the process of tests development
   - protocol-based tests execution speed is much higher
   - running tests in parallel is something performance testing tools support out of the box
   - you can always use either full test or lesser subset for identifying performance bottlenecks and ensure that there are no degradations caused by new functionality or bug fixes
   - wider protocols support
3. Use free and open source software where possible as:

   - you can always look into sources to see how this or that bit is implemented
   - if some feature is missing, incorrectly works or isn't optimal - you can implement or change required functionality and contribute your improvements

Hopefully above approaches will help you to identify the best strategy and narrow down tools list to manageable and reasonable size.

See [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) guide for example research of identifying a test tool.